# Count no. of ones by position(place) of an array of 32-bit binary numbers

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

An `array(10^5 size)` of 32-bit binary numbers is given, we're required to count the no. of ones for every bit of those numbers.

**For example:**

```
Array :  {10101,1011,1010,1}  
Counts : {1's place: 3, 2's place: 2, 3's place: 1, 4's place: 2, 5's place: 1}
```

No bit manipulation technique seems to satisfy the constraints to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this should be solveable with two loops: one going over the array the other one masking the right bits. Running time should be not too bad for your constraints.

Here is a rust implementation (out of my head, not throughtfully tested):

```
fn main() {

    let mut v = vec!();

    for i in 1..50*1000 {
        v.push(i);
    }

    let r = bitcount_arr(v);

    r.iter().enumerate().for_each( |(i,x)| print!("index {}:{} ",i+1,x));


}


fn bitcount_arr(input:Vec<u32>) -> [u32;32] {

    let mut res = [0;32];

    for num in input {

        for i in 0..31 {
            let mask = 1 << i;

            if num & mask != 0 {
                res[i] += 1;        
            }
        }

    }
    res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with transposed addition, though the array is a bit long for it.

To transpose addition, use an array of counters, but instead of using one counter for every *position* we'll use one counter for every *bit of the count*. So a counter that tracks for each position whether the count is even/odd, a counter that tracks for each position whether the count has a 2 in it, etc.

To add an element of the array into this, only half-add operations (`&` to find the new carry, `^` to update) are needed, since it's only a conditional increment: (not tested)

```
uint32_t counters[17];
for (uint32_t elem : array) {
    uint32_t c = elem;
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        uint32_t nextcarry = counters[i] & c;
        counters[i] ^= c;
        c = nextcarry;
    }
}
```

I chose 17 counters because `log2(10^5)` is just less than 17. So even if all bits are 1, the counters won't wrap.

To read off the result for bit `k`, take the `k`'th bit of every counter.

There are slightly more efficient ways that can add several elements of the array into the counters at once using some full-adds and duplicated counters.